# C# Network Discovery Not Working (Windows)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to read devices on the network in C#, basically the way they appear in the "Network" tab in File Explorer.

The only way I can find to do it is this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using which uses `NetServerEnum()`

No matter how hard I search on Google, everything always eventually leads back to that link. But it doesn't work at all! I'm using this code:

```
static class Network {
    [DllImport("Netapi32")]
    static extern int NetServerEnum(string ServerNane, int dwLevel, ref IntPtr pBuf, int dwPrefMaxLen,
    out int dwEntriesRead, out int dwTotalEntries, int dwServerType, string domain, out int dwResumeHandle);

    [DllImport("Netapi32")]
    static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr pBuf);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct SERVER_INFO_100 {
        internal int id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        internal string name;
    }

    static int SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION = 1, SV_TYPE_SERVER = 2;
    static int SSIZE = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SERVER_INFO_100));

    public static ArrayList GetNetwork() {
        ArrayList net = new ArrayList();

        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero, tmpBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        int read = 0, total = 0, handle = 0;

        try {
            int ret = NetServerEnum(null, 100, ref buffer, -1, out read, out total, SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION | SV_TYPE_SERVER, null, out handle);
            if(ret != 0) Console.WriteLine("Error Code "+ret+": "+new Win32Exception(ret).Message);
            Console.WriteLine(read+" of "+total);
            if(ret == 0) {
                for(int i=0; i<total; i++) {
                    tmpBuffer = new IntPtr((long)buffer + (i*SSIZE));
                    SERVER_INFO_100 inf = (SERVER_INFO_100)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer, typeof(SERVER_INFO_100));
                    net.Add(inf.name);
                }
            }
            NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with acessing network computers in NetworkBrowser"
            +"\r\n\r\n\r\n"+ex.Message,"Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
        return net;
    }
}
```

The error code I get is:

```
Error Code 1231: The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help
```

What? I'm not even *trying* to reach a network location yet! And this error code isn't listed in the possible error codes on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370623(v=vs.85).aspx). What am I doing wrong?

Why is this basic functionality of using the Windows Network Discovery already built-in to the OS so difficult, in an API literally called .NET?

Comment: Works for me. Do you have something that has a Master Browser or Computer Browser role locally?

Comment: IDK but I have network discovery and network file sharing on. My network set up is pretty standard and usually just works. And in File Explorer I can see everything on my network. About 5 computers, a NAT, a printer, and my WiFi router. Oh also I don't have a homegroup set up. Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yes, well, the API functions you are using require a local Browser (Server or Workstation). See, in Windows Services whether the Computer Browser service is running.

Comment: The Wikipedia article (which makes no sense to me) seems to say that is only included in Windows Server. I only have Windows 10 Pro... I actually do have a home server, but it's running Linux (the obvious OS of choice for headless servers). Anyway, it sounds like this is for enterprise networks or something, so is this different from regular Windows Network Discovery, in which case how do I do that?

Comment: What is only included in Windows Server? However, I tested it on a Windows 7 workstation. This error was quite common in Windows Vista, usually related to a bad routing configuration. Sometimes resolved disabling the IPV6. Other times, enabling NetBios over TcpIp (Network Connections/IpV4/Properties/Advanced/Wins). Any Windows Workstation has a Computer Browser service. Just verify it's running (sometimes it's not).

Comment: There are other, more recent, ways to browse a network. But SO is not the right Site for this kind of discussions.

Comment: Okay I found it in the services list. It already said running but I restarted the service and now the program is working somehow, but it only gives 2 devices back. This computer, and one of my two printers. No computers or router or my NAT (which is what I actually want, to find PCs and NATs), or even the other printer... I don't think I have a workgroup or domain or anything, so null for domain should work right?

Comment: The code you're using is searching form Servers and Workstations only. Take a look at MSDN for more options. There are many more.

Comment: I tried the other options and I got a few more devices but not everything, but now it's giving the 1231 error again and restarting the service doesn't work anymore. I don't think it's a very good solution honestly. If it doesn't work for me it won't work for the people who install my app... Anyway I also saw an answer on SO that said to use the `Environment.SpecialFolder.NetworkShortcuts` folder, but for me that folder is always empty.